# Eliminar URI de un link con php (http://misitio.com/uri/uri/loquesea)

Tags: php

Me gustaría eliminar como en el ejemplo en el título de la pregunta con PHP la URI, es decir lo que sigue de una URL.

`http://misitio.com/uri/uri/loquesea` --> `http://misitio.com`

---

@RobertoLeónOramas Estoy solicitando un sanitizer de php no una regla de rewrite de htaccess.

@MrViKxD Regresa el hostname en el que se accede el sitio , necesito un sanitizer, eso no es lo que necesito.

Comment: No debes poner algo en subniveles si quieres accederlo directamente; basta lo pongas en raiz el sitio y lo nombres index.html, default.html, o cualquiera sea el nombre de las que estan por default establecidas. Por cierto esta consulta expuesta tiene la misma finalidad del que desde hace días pide lo de acortadores.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el array $_SERVER

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = explode('/', $url);
$url = implode('/', array_slice($url, 0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es extraer el dominio actual bastaría con:

```
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //HTTP_HOST devuelve el dominio.com o www.dominio.com
    $host = 'http://'.$host //Si quieres añadir http
```

Si lo que quieres es una función que a partir de una url se quede con la parte de dominio:

```
    $url = 'http://misitio.com/uri/uri/loquesea';
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    print $parse['host']; // devuelve misitio.com
    print $parse['scheme'].'//'.$parse['host']; //devuelve http://misitio.com
```

Puedes encontrar la documentación de `parse_url($url)` aquí:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php